# Parameters in javascriptmethods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I haven't understand the function definition inside a method in javascript. 
For example in AngularJS I have th code:

```
sth.controller('ctrlname', function ($scope, $ionicModal, par3, par4){
       //code
});
```

I also have th code:

```
var f = function (par5,par6){
     return par5 + par6;
}
```

If I call f(2,3) I get the result 5.

So in controller and other similar examples I choose arbitrary names for the parameters inside function or variables that exists previously?

Comment: In javascript, you can pass a function as a paramter to another function. I suggest you read about `callbacks` in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MikeFeltman said, you can use any name for your functions' arguments
**BUT**
Angular as its own logic for dependency injection and it can use argument's name to identify which piece of software your controller/service/etc depends on.

Let's create a `B` controller that depends on a `A` service:

```
angular.module("testModule",[])
.service("A",function(){
//do stuff
})
.controller("B",function(A){
//do other stuff
});
```

Angular injector, will look at the `B` constructor's arguments (here `A`) and try to find the expected service.

But you can name your arguments as you want :

```
angular.module("testModule",[])
.service("A",function(){
//do stuff
})
.controller("B",["A",function(dontCareAboutVarName){
//do other stuff
}]);
```

Here the injector, won't look at the function's arguments as it will find an array describing the dependencies and, the last item will be the controller constructor.

Please, take a look at the documentation about [angular's injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are new variables from within the functions, regardless of it they exist already or not, but I would not use the same names as variables that are available from the containing function in order to avoid confusion. I'd recommend reading up on closures in JavaScript to get a better understanding of this. This is a pretty decent read on them: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in controller like this ..

```
    sth.controller('ctrlname', function ($scope, $ionicModal, par3, par4){
        //function...
       $scope.sum = function(par3,par4){
           return par3 + par4 ;
       }
    });
```